# How to change listview data with multiply checkbox checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want change the listview data with checkboxlist items. But when checked 2 or multiply items write this error:
The variable name '@TId' has already been declared.

or

Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Please help me. :(

HTML:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ltvProduct" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hypProduct" NavigateUrl='<%#"show.aspx?NId="+Eval("MId") %>'>
            <div class="col-lg-4 Border Text PContainer ">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"/img/Gallery/"+Eval("PicUrl") %>' CssClass="padding-product" Width="240px" /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' CssClass="EnName"></asp:Label><br />
            </div>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

CHECKBOX BIND CODE:

```
SqlConnection conT = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSTR"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmT = new SqlCommand("Select * from Type", conT);
            SqlDataAdapter adpT = new SqlDataAdapter(cmT);
            DataTable dtT = new DataTable();
            adpT.Fill(dtT);
            chkType.DataSource = dtT;
            chkType.DataTextField = "Name";
            chkType.DataValueField = "TId";
            chkType.DataBind();
```

SELECTEDINDEXCHANGE:

```
string strconnectionP = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CSTR"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection objconnectionP = new SqlConnection(strconnectionP);
        string strsqlP = "select * from Model where TId=@TId";
        SqlCommand objcommandP = new SqlCommand(strsqlP, objconnectionP);
        for (int i = 0; i < chkType.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chkType.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                objcommandP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TId", chkType.SelectedValue[i]);
                objconnectionP.Open();
                ltvProduct.DataSource = objcommandP.ExecuteReader();
                ltvProduct.DataBind();     
            }
            objconnectionP.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

In your `SELECTEDINDEXCHANGE` event you are executing your `SqlCommand` inside a loop for multiple times. If you want to use a `SqlCommand` multiple times you should clear your parameter everytime after executing `SqlCommand`. Use this line of code

```
objcommandP.Parameters.Clear();
```

Ater these lines

```
 ltvProduct.DataSource = objcommandP.ExecuteReader();
 ltvProduct.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks. But show again this error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: It is because your loop is not the right way to do this. Try to loop like these `  foreach (ListItem item in this.CheckBoxList1.Items){if (item.Selected){s1 = item.ToString(); objcommandP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TId", s1; objconnectionP.Open();  ltvProduct.DataSource = objcommandP.ExecuteReader();
 ltvProduct.DataBind();}}`

Comment: Thank you. Very well. All of errors is cleared. But when checked all items, just show one of the selected items data.

Comment: foreach (ListItem item in this.chkType.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    string s1 = item.Value.ToString();
                    objcommandP.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TId", s1);
                    objconnectionP.Open();
                    ltvProduct.DataSource = objcommandP.ExecuteReader();
                    ltvProduct.DataBind();
                    objcommandP.Parameters.Clear();
                }
                objconnectionP.Close();
            }